# Не работает подсказка у area в Chrome и Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться!

Есть изображение и его map area, по наведению на которое должна появляться подсказка.

По какой-то причине подсказка не работает в Google Chrome и Safari - судя по всему, не срабатывают события. Можно как-то это обойти или проэмулировать? Или, может, кто знает какой jQuery плагин, корректно работающий в такой ситуации?

```
 $(function () {
     $('.allod').mouseover(function () {
         $('#hint').css("visibility", "visible").css("cursor", "pointer");
     }).mouseout(function () {
         $('#hint').css("visibility", "hidden").css("cursor", "default");
     }).mousemove(function (e) {
         h = $('#hint').height() * 3;
         w = $('#hint').width() + 15;
         $('#hint').css("left", (e.pageX + w)+"px").css("top", (e.pageY - h)+"px");
     });
 })
```

[Демонстрация на jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/t1nk/BZLkM/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [баг в chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128527). Возможно, это относится к Webkit.

Comment: Видимо так и есть, поскольку в Safari аналогичная проблема.
А как обойти этот баг не знаете ?

Comment: Печально...  
Что же буду искать дальше.

Comment: @t1nk в последнем обновлении Chrome исправлено

Comment: Возможно...  
Я ставил его из offline-утановщика, поэтому он у меня не обновляется автоматом. Скорее всего я не один такой - поэтому нужно решение...

Answer (score 1):

Вот это попробуйте - http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

> Tested with
>
> ```
> Firefox
> IE 6, 7, 8, 9
> Safari 3, 4, 5
> Chrome
> Opera 9, 10
> ```